# Update column through different databases

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have two database `3dside` and `3dside_old`. I want to update a column in 3dside from 3dside_old where two fields are the same (cases.id_cases).

I tried something like that :

```
UPDATE cases SET hospital_id = (SELECT hospital_id FROM 3dside_old.cases)   
WHERE 3dside.cases.id_cases = 3dside_old.cases.id_cases;
```

But I have `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column '3dside_old.cases.id_cases' in 'where clause'`

How to declare another database in a where clause ?

I am pretty new with MySQL, sorry if the answer seems easy for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a better way using JOIN and giving alias names to the tables as

```
update `3dside`.`cases` c1
join `3dside_old`.`cases` c2 on c2.id_cases = c1.id_cases
set c1.hospital_id = c2.hospital_id
```

Comment: I had to disable the "safe-mode" in Workbench but it worked !